# Query expressions add new with AND and OR

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I try to create and chain expression with a different conjunction, but it seems I do not understand how does it work.

```
$e = new QueryExpression();
$e->add(['OR' => '1=2']);
$e->add($e->and_('3=4'));
$e->add($e->or_('5=6'));
$e->add(['AND' => '7=8']);
```

The result of the above is

> (1=2 AND 3=4 AND 5=6 AND 7=8)

How do I add `AND` and `OR` conjunctions?

Comment: Can you please write the query you want to reproduce

Comment: @SamHecquet There is no particular query what I want to create. I have created a utility for a CakePHP 3 accounting project. I have a base query and I have to add query expression what can be conjucted via AND and OR .

Comment: Check **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions**.

Comment: @ndm I read the documentation and the API but somehow it is still not clear for me. I am trying to build up the expression chain in a loop. Could you please take a look? 
https://gist.github.com/rrd108/8f814acb3c50f423c95f6f5be2221efe 
I am quite sure that I was missing something simple.

Comment: You need to add the OR conditions to the expression that is being returned by `or_()`.

Comment: @ndm Thank you so much. You always know what is the right answer :) I updated the gist wit my solution.